# Sorting on grouped items in a grid

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I'm new DevExpress controls.

I've a C#/WPF application in which I'm using LayoutGroup to group the contents by AccountId.

When I click Active(Y/N) column header, I need to be able to sort the complete grid contents.Right now, its sorting only the first group.

```
MyWindow.xaml

    <UserControl 
    ....
    xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
    xmlns:dxdo="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/docking"
    ....
    ....
    >

    <dxdo:LayoutGroup>
    .....

    <dx:GridColumn Header="Active(Y/N)" FieldName="IsActive"  />
    <dx:GridColumn Header="AccountId" GroupIndex="0" FieldName="AccountId"  />

    </dxdo:LayoutGroup>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Share proper xaml code. None can help by this.

Comment: Set AllowSorting Property to true. Check this https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.DataViewBase.AllowSorting.property